# Bootstrap Date and Time Picker not showing icons in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I´m trying to setup a date and time picker, but the icons (Calendar and Time) does not shows up. Here is my code:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    Date and Time Test
                    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" />
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            language: 'pt-BR'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I´ve tried to change icon-time and icon-calendar to glyphicon-time and glyicon-calendar and no success.

Here is what I get:

[image]

Don´t know what to do.. I need help, please. Thanks.

Comment: have you included the appropriate bootstrap css files?

Comment: As mentioned in @Jasen answer, you need the class attribute which I think you are confusing here with data attributes.

    data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"

Comment: I'd make sure the Bootstrap version for your site is compatible with the plugin.

Comment: My version is Bootstrap 3. I´m including:<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text"> on this code and     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
on the _Layout. Bootstrap is working (I´ve several other objects, like NavBar, etc. not showed here).

Comment: The icon names in your code for the date time picker suggest it uses version 2. You'll need to look more closely at the plugin's code to know for sure. I would expect problems since the rest of your site is using version 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website for the tarruda bootstrap-datetimepicker.js that you are using says the plugin is not currently maintained.  It does not appear to have been upgraded for Bootstrap 3.

I'd suggest one of these date/time picker plugins that are compatible with Bootstrap 3:

- http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
- http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

And if you really want to get the one you are using to work, you can try making manual changes to the JS and CSS.  Follow the blog post "Datepicker for Bootstrap with Twitter Bootstrap 3.0" found at kenyontechnology.  The post was written for the date-only plugin on which the date/time plugin you are using was forked, so I think the changes should mostly apply.